# why i am not able to use the default theme properties in makeStyle?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

why I am getting error for using any theme properties of default theme also error is coming that can't read proporties of undefine (reading 'down)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Paper, Typography} from '@mui/material';
import {makeStyles} from '@mui/styles'
function LogMu() {
    const useStyle= makeStyles(theme => 
    ({
        loginbox:{
           height: 400,
           width: 350,
           
           display: 'flex',
           justifyContent : "center",
           padding: 20,
          
           [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
          },
        }
    })
    )
    const classes = useStyle()
    return (
        
<div>   
           
               <Paper className={classes.loginbox} justifyContent="center">
<Typography> Login</Typography>
               </Paper>
           
        </div>
    );
}

export default LogMu;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting this error because you doesn't wrapped your app with `ThemeProvider`.

Something like this:

```js
const theme = createTheme();

export function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BaseComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Said that, avoid use `makeStyles` with `@Mui` v5. You can check their [docs](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/).

> @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

So, you probably should go with [Style Components](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#styled-components).

And your code could be something like this:

```js
import { Paper, Typography } from "@mui/material";

import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const CustomizedPaper = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  height: 400,
  width: 350,

  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  padding: 20,

  [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  }
}));

export const StyledExample = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomizedPaper>
        <Typography>Styled Example</Typography>
      </CustomizedPaper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also did a [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-style-components-vs-makestyles-oriwrs?file=/src/App.js) to you check out the 2 ways.
/* With `makestyles` you need to add `!important` because `@Mui` root classes overwrite your custom `background-color`.